# IsomorphicGraphQ issues?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.2 and fixed in 11.3.**

This bug is specific to Windows.

---

When I evaluate

`ga = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}];gb = Graph[{1 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3}];IsomorphicGraphQ[ga, gb]`,

Mathematica returns

[image].

It does return `False` when I evaluate `IsomorphicGraphQ[x,y]`.

The same occurs when I try to evaluate the functions given in the documentation.

Is it a know/recent issue ? I have found nothing online. I am using version 11.2 on Windows 64-bits.

Thank you.

Comment: I experienced the `IsomorphicGraphQ` issue as well, only on my Windows machine. I do not experience it on macOS. I am almost 100% certain it is a bug with Mathematica 11.2 on Windows.

Comment: M11.3 is said to be nearing release. I'd expect such a serious bug to be fixed by then (but I do not know).

Comment: Yes, it has been fixed in M11.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsomorphicGraphQ` not evaluating is a known bug in Mathematica 11.2 for Windows.  The bug is not present in older versions (<= 11.1) or in M11.2 for Mac and Linux.

As a workaround, you can use a different version of Mathematica, or you can use my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), which has multiple isomorphism testing functions.  The drawback is that all IGraph/M functions have an overhead due to the need to convert the graph to the [igraph](http://igraph.org/) format.  Because of this, IGraph/M's isomorphism functions will be considerably slower than the built-in ones for *small* graphs.  For big graphs (or for hard problems) `IGBlissIsomorphicQ` will be faster than the built-in function.

---

Examples:

```
g1 = IGShorthand["1-2-3-4-1"]
```

[image]

```
g2 = IGShorthand["a-d, a-b, d-c, b-c"]
```

[image]

```
IGIsomorphicQ[g1, g2]
(* True *)

IGBlissGetIsomorphism[g1, g2]
(* {<|1 -> "a", 2 -> "d", 3 -> "c", 4 -> "b"|>} *)

IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[g1]
(* {{1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 4, 3}} *)

GroupElements@PermutationGroup[%]
(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{2, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}}]} *)
```

Comment: Indeed. I have edited the original question accordingly. Thank you.